# Implement Casio's M

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

### The task

Most Casio calculators featured a variable `M`, which has 3 operators related to it: `M`, `M+`, and `M-`

`M`, as you can expect, returns the value stored in the variable.

`M+` takes the number on the left and add it to `M`.

`M-` does the same thing as `M+`, but subtract instead.

To make the challenge just a bit more difficult, we will add an extra operator: `MR`, which is short for `Memory reset`. As you can guess from the name, it resets the variable `M` back to 0.

Your task is to parse a string of Casio `M` expression, then print the value of `M`.

Here's an example:

```
9M+9M+
```

Here, we add `9` to variable `M` twice, so the output will be `18`.

### Specifications

- `M` will be `0` when first initialized
- For this challenge, you don't need to handle basic arithmetics, just those operators.
- However, you do need to handle implicit multiplications, so `9M` will become `81` for `M = 9`
- If the expression given is invalid, you can return any value of your choice
- `M+` and `M-` must not have an operator behind them (except for `M`), so cases like `MRM+` and `9M+M+` are invalid, but `9M+MM+` is valid.

### Input/Output

The input should be a string and the output is either the variable `M` or an invalid value of your choice.

### Testcases

```
Input -> Output
9M+9M+ -> 18
9MR9M+ -> 9
9M+MM+ -> 18
9M-9M-9M+ -> -9
9M+MMM+ -> 90
81M+81M+56M-35M-12M+ -> 83
9M+MRM+ -> Invalid
9M+M+  -> Invalid
9 -> 0 (Explanation: does not modify M with an operator)
9M+MM -> 9 (Same as the above test case)
2M+2M2MM+ -> 18
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25330/107017)

Comment: Could you please clarify `9M+MMM+ -> 90`?

Comment: @Arnauld we first add `9` to `M = 0` so `M` becomes `9`. `MM`  is equivalent of `M*M` -> `9*9` -> `81`, then we add it to `M` to make `M` to `90`. The expression is equivalent to `9M+81M+`.

Comment: Is `9` a valid expression? Can an expression end with something other than `M+`, `M-`, or `MR`?

Comment: @gsitcia Yes. In that case `M` will just be `0`. And also yes, an expression can end without any operators, in that case the leftover value at the end should not modify `M`. So `9M+MM` will just print out `9`

Comment: My Casio calculator is so old that `MR` is the Memory Read button.

Comment: @Neil Mine is so old that `MR` is nonexistent.

Comment: The return a falsey value on an invalid input is rather annoying, since in a language without implicit coercion the only falsey value is `false` and if the language is statically typed that means you basically can't do the challenge, since a function can only return objects of a single type and this specification requires returning both booleans and integers.

Comment: @WheatWizard I have also thought of relaxing the invalid output, but couldn't think of a language in the time. Edited.

Comment: Would something like `2M+2M2MM+` be valid?  If so, I assume the answer would be `18`?

Comment: @Jonah Yes, that is valid, and yes, you are right that the answer is `18`

Comment: @oeuf You may want to add `2M+2M2MM+` to the test case, because only one of the current four answers handles it correctly.. :/

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. Added.

Answer (score 5):

## Python3, 287 bytes:

```py
import re
R=re.findall
V=lambda m,x,k=1:k if[]==x else V(m,x[1:],k*(int(x[0])if x[0].isdigit()else m))
E=lambda x,M=0:M if[]==x else E(x[1:],M+[-1,1][x[0][1][-1]!='-']*V(M,R('\d+|M',x[0][0]))*(x[0][1]!='MR'))
f=lambda x:''.join(map(''.join,k:=R('([M\d]+)(M(?:\-|\+)|MR)',x)))==x and E(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY89b4MwEIZ3fgWdfI5tFDdKlSJZnTLewpDFeKACWpdPEQYq8d@pnaRV8yGdddZ7r5/33H@Pn1272fXDstim74YxHIogUUMRlbbNs7oODqrOmvc8Cxs@8UrJuAptqY1SU1jUxyI8gBtoGRtercC2I0x6bagtQ98je8zthx2BnrwNpcH@lzdxVOsYr2l7OLOQaSG5NNpTtOtCmidFBDGrAyBPgKQ5m5Hw09wF0hVcrM6GCXFJ5V9STEj01dkWmqyHy51XsXIY0JjmhlFAeItTMaeMzphQB6aU@rWyNndbVXTpB/@7EsgrMlc@4Z@U3EsM7yRxqmsVz9teP7zx7CQyf7YvKDZbFPL5QVpyC763eGX5AQ)

Comment: [279 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY9Pa8MwDMXv/RTZyVJsh3qlowuYnXrUJYdeXB86kmxe/pJmkEG/e@a021ibgozg6en35Parf2/q1abtxtFVbdP1QZctEt1lUe7q9FCWi50uD9VreggqMYhCq7gIXG6s1kOQlccs2IEfGBVbUYTg6h4Gs7To8mDqkTum7s31gGdvhbjY/vIGQXoZ0zVtCxcWcSOVUNZMFOO7VPZBM8lsuAMSCbB9yk/ExHnuAzGEH6u3UcJ8Uv6XFANj0Ufjajh@VlDE2u@DoX1qOQLBS2wkt3iiBD0QBSCivwjDLRQ4tt30qxzYM3FfE/mflMwlTjNJnutapcuV14s3no0iPr31E8nVmqR6vJOW3ILnlkkZvwE)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>172</s> <s>179</s> <s>174</s> <s>169</s> <s>164</s> <s>156</s></sup> 153 bytes

```python
def f(x,M=0):
 try:exec(s("M(?=\d|M)","M*",s("(\d|M)M","\\1*M",s("R=","*=0M",s("(.*?)(M[-+R])",r"\2=\1;",x))))+"\nprint(M)")
 except:0
import re
s=re.sub
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVDBTuMwEBVXf8XIl9iNEyVFoLbI5czBWqkcCUIsdcBScSLbRa3Ej6C99ML-E3wNEzvLdteypXnvzZvxzK_f_T48dfZweN-Gtph9vK11Cy3bCSUrviAQ3H6hd_qBeUYVu5TN-lVxKqiaUIEUi1gh0TT1REVuJRFOZJUQKyeXnKmbIl_dotHRZiqb-oKKHceT08b2ztjAsConoHcPug-LipjnvnMBnCZeOl367c_0wc-T5Sj5vf-TZTpC2s7BxlgNxg5S6cPaWBwAj7G9wMo9SHi-75kPDlVnkBwMpe83JjAKxRIo5yRaxgrdNgi4SwG6TVdeo9E-Xv1glHJxlBZdLcNWPIbJ8FcvH3V4ud9sNeOpOeP_NcL0sRM5qpBdWbSZdQamTZQESkFvvIbv1LTBUcVBRRo5K5aZgDhDJmUWd8DTGg8f73OV4x2mrmdkrlYjmGOcqyOhiDfiYhTHzIrMapUP7-xcFadnqqinSZqdxsRVQuMIkcrhH2YAVSqammOBqZp-90-__QI)

-3 bytes thanks to [@The Thonnu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/114446/the-thonnu)

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>148</s> <s>155</s> <s>150</s> <s>145</s> <s>140</s></sup> 137 bytes

```python
lambda x,M=0:exec(s("M(?=\d|M)","M*",s("(\d|M)M","\\1*M",s("R=","*=0M",s("(.*?)(M[-+R])",r"\2=\1;",x))))+"\nprint(M)")
import re
s=re.sub
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVBLTsMwFBTbnMLyJnbjRE0rUFtkWLOwkMqSIBSoA5ZSJ7JdlEpcgDOwYVPuBKfhxQ6lICxH8cybeb_X93brHhv9tqsQR8Vu46p09vFSl-u7VYk6Jvh4ITt5TyzBgpzzYvUsKGZYjDADingsgCiKfCQ8t-QAR3wcEMlG55SI6zRZ3oDR4GLCi_wUs47CSXChW6O0I5CVRmrdNsYhIyPLjczs5i409HlUDiG7td8q1URR1RhUKy2R0vC3jkA8s26lNF1ECI7SLUOya2G4ddkS6wyEjQKyt2W2rZUjGKVnCFPqHc5sg7U_Q7pm4xi6DQ_IpJrsCpLoh4tLgjFlB7K9syJQmu5hMP7osgfpnsp6IwkNDZGgld29bN3ijy--0CBWq9jzldJlXf_bJWhvDxoJq_U877fAwj7i9CxmyA8Vcx77BdGw6beP3VwkcPuV5LNoLpYDmMM7EQeB1F-P0yE4KMfRLBdJ_x2fiHR6LNJ8EkKzqRcuAxqm8lSCfjE9GIekoTgkmIjJvn7o9gs)

Shorter version which throws an error for invalid expressions.

+7 bytes to both versions due to bug in code.

Comment: [153 by changing `pass` to `0`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVDBTuMwEBVXf8XIl9iNEyVFoLbI5czBWqkcCUIsdcBScSLbRa3Ej6C99ML-E3wNEzvLdteypXnvzZvxzK_f_T48dfZweN-Gtph9vK11Cy3bCSUrviAQ3H6hd_qBeUYVu5TN-lVxKqiaUIEUi1gh0TT1REVuJRFOZJUQKyeXnKmbIl_dotHRZiqb-oKKHceT08b2ztjAsConoHcPug-LipjnvnMBnCZeOl367c_0wc-T5Sj5vf-TZTpC2s7BxlgNxg5S6cPaWBwAj7G9wMo9SHi-75kPDlVnkBwMpe83JjAKxRIo5yRaxgrdNgi4SwG6TVdeo9E-Xv1glHJxlBZdLcNWPIbJ8FcvH3V4ud9sNeOpOeP_NcL0sRM5qpBdWbSZdQamTZQESkFvvIbv1LTBUcVBRRo5K5aZgDhDJmUWd8DTGg8f73OV4x2mrmdkrlYjmGOcqyOhiDfiYhTHzIrMapUP7-xcFadnqqinSZqdxsRVQuMIkcrhH2YAVSqammOBqZp-90-__QI)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 248 bytes

```
\d+|M
¶$&
\d+
*
{`^(.*)¶(_*¶)?MR|^.*¶M[-+](¶.*)*

+`^(.*)(¶-?_*¶?)M(?!.)
$1$2$1
^(.*¶-?)(_*)¶(-?)(_*)(?!.)
$1$3$.2*$4
--

^(.*)¶(.*)¶M([-+])
$1$3$2
\+-
-
--
+
^(_*)\+|^(-_*)-|^-(_*)\+\3|^(-_*?)(_*)\+\5
$1$2$4
)`(_+)-\1(\B)?
$#2*-
L$`^(-?)(_*)
$1$.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xTsQwDIZ3vwUih5xYjpT0irgpEssteOlK6BUJBhaG0230ufoAfbHiNAHJyW/7/2T7@nn7@n4P2wHP05Y/aBZYF/MAmoKDn2lE7@y64MWti00yzKPXTF6Z3nBd1HMAVCmtORUuWcF05y2YYKIJUNziWZ1SZrXsn@mMj84cgRngb9/@C5Y9jYmQiYELRYrpgEzziKwJzyPXRu5qq27Quq9HHMFOeCHLOWB@tgnMfXQML0ZPb@cU0MdtOwlpwEmGKiS78B6tofoUhMrrH4W7XjjEZg5N9a/wLw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+|M
¶$&
```

Insert newlines before each number or memory operation. The newline before the very first operation serves to set the initial memory to zero.

```
\d+
*
```

Convert all the numbers to unary.

```
{`
)`
```

Repeat until all of the numbers and memory operations have been processed.

```
^(.*)¶(_*¶)?MR|^.*¶M[-+](¶.*)*
```

`MR` will reset just the memory and `M-` or `M+` in an invalid place will clear everything resulting in an output of zero.

```
+`^(.*)(¶-?_*¶?)M(?!.)
$1$2$1
```

`M` either immediately after an `MR`, `M-` or `M+`, or with a number in between, will read the memory.

```
^(.*¶-?)(_*)¶(-?)(_*)(?!.)
$1$3$.2*$4
--
```

Two values (at least one of which will have been the result of a memory read) will multiply together.

```
^(.*)¶(.*)¶M([-+])
$1$3$2
\+-
-
--
+
^(_*)\+|^(-_*)-|^-(_*)\+\3|^(-_*?)(_*)\+\5
$1$2$4
(_+)-\1(\B)?
$#2*-
```

`M+` and `M-` after the value will add it to or subtract it from the memory.

```
L$`^(-?)(_*)
$1$.2
```

Convert the final memory to decimal, ignoring any pending value.

Comment: Seems to fail for `2M+2M2MM+ -> 18`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen At the time it wasn't obvious that numbers after `M` needed to be supported, but I guess I'll look at it at some point.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>78</s> 72 bytes

```
≔¹ηＦ⪪⁺RθM«¿⊙ι№-+Rκ«≡§ι⁰-¿υ≧⁻Πυζ≔⁰η+¿υ≧⁺Πυζ≔⁰η≔⁰ζ≔⟦⟧υ≔Φιλι»⊞υζ¿ι⊞υＩι»¿ηＩζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZA9a8MwFEXn@Fc8NOlhGdKM8RQChQ4Ck46lg/BH9IiQU0vqh0t@uyvZbulSKELLPVdHT6q1GupemWk6OEdny@8EaCyzrh@AP14NeV6Z4Dg7MQEvKIBJhgif2YY64Af7wUnAsQ/Wc1bkqXTBhW/cG/lax5J/sE37norbFdXKtcAKtodkCQhSXZf7T3TWnkuywQmohr4JtY8FASOW0Jp4bJ1zu8z57cr/dKXx/6lq2k4F4/e/wDiDW9xr9vQsIMzhGtyT8e2QXmeimxKK9dlfBad5WCVpOsKf7Kic56l9yxLRkQwUf3HOR8RymnaykLu48ql4NV8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔¹η
```

Start by assuming the expression is valid.

```
Ｆ⪪⁺RθM«
```

Split the input on `M` and loop over the parts, however prefix an `R` to the first part to get a free memory reset.

```
¿⊙ι№-+Rκ«
```

If this part contains a `-`, `+` or `R`, then:

```
≡§ι⁰
```

Switch over the first character in the part.

```
-¿υ≧⁻Πυζ≔⁰η
```

If it's a `-` then subtract the product of the stack from the memory, but if the stack is empty then mark the expression as invalid.

```
+¿υ≧⁺Πυζ≔⁰η
```

Similarly for `+`.

```
≔⁰ζ
```

Otherwise, this is an `R`, so clear the memory.

```
≔⟦⟧υ
```

Clear the stack.

```
≔Φιλι
```

Remove the leading character from the part.

```
»⊞υζ
```

Otherwise, push the memory to the stack.

```
¿ι⊞υＩι
```

If the part isn't empty then push its value to the stack.

```
»¿ηＩζ
```

If the expression was valid then output the memory.

Comment: Seems to fail for `2M+2M2MM+ -> 18`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen At the time it wasn't obvious that numbers after `M` needed to be supported, but I guess I'll look at it at some point.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I took the opportunity to change my approach and as a bonus it's now 10% shorter!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>52</s> 47 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0U…+-RS©D¶«.:¶¡ε®'Mì„X+…Xs-‚…)\0ª'U«:'M„XP:.V}X
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fIPRRwzJt3aDgQytdDm07tFrPCkguPLf10Dp138NrHjXMi9AGKogo1n3UMAvI0IwxOLRKPfTQait1X5BkgJVeWG3E//9GvtpGvka@vtr/dXXz8nVzEqsqAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/g9BHDcu0dYOCD610ObTt0Go9KyC58NzWQ@vUfQ@vedQwL0IbqCCiWPdRwywgQzPG4NAq9dBDq63UfUGSAVZ6YbUR/130Dq9/1Lng8IJMJc@8ssSczBSlWp3/0UqWvtpApKQDZATBGNq@UIYuGMEFwSwLQ19tEDY189U1NvXVNTSCKwiCs8A0TBuQBqox8jUCGRD7X1c3L183J7GqEgA).

**Explanation:**"

```python
0U            # Set variable `X` to 0 (it's 1 by default)
…+-RSD¶«.:¶¡  # Split the (implicit) input after each "+"/"-"/"R":
…+-RS         #  Push triplet ["+","-","R"]
     ©        #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
      D       #  Duplicate it
       ¶«     #  Append a newline to the values in the pair
         .:   #  Replace all "+"/"-"/"R" with "+\n"/"-\n"/"R\n" respectively in the
              #  (implicit) input
           ¶¡ #  Then split on newlines
ε             # Map over each substring:
              # (used as a foreach, where all will have their own separated stack):
 ®            #  Push triplet ["+","-","R"] from variable `®`
  'Mì        '#  Prepend an "M" in front of each
 „X+          #  Push string "X+"
     ‚        #  Pair it with
 …Xs-         #  String "Xs-"
     ª        #  And also append
 …)\0         #  String ")\0"
      'U«    '#  Append an "U" after all three: ["X+U","Xs-U",")\0U"]
 :            #  Replace all "M+"/"M-"/"MR" with "X+U"/"Xs-U"/")\0U" respectively
 'M„XP:      '#  Then replace all remaining "M" with "XP"
 .V           #  Execute it as 05AB1E code (see below)
}X            # After the map: push value `X`
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
)\0U          # MR:
)             #  Wrap the entire stack into a list
 \            #  Discard it
  0U          #  Reset `X` to 0

X+U           # M+:
X+            #  Add `X` to the top value
  U           #  Pop and store it as new value `X`

Xs-U          # M-:
X             #  Push `X`
 s            #  Wrap the top two values on the stack
  -           #  Subtract the value from `X`
   U          #  Pop and store it as new value `X`

XP            # Remaining M:
X             #  Push value `X`
 P            #  Get the product of all values on the stack (for the current group)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, 40 bytes

```
⁽±ḊƛǍ[f;f(nw‛MR‛¥⁼½dĿ÷Ė‟n±ß¥£!3=ß*)¥D⌊=*
```

[Test suite](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJEQSIsIiIsIuKBvcKx4biKxpvHjVtmO2YobnfigJtNUuKAm8Kl4oG8wr1kxL/Dt8SW4oCfbsKxw5/CpcKjITM9w58qKcKlROKMij0qIiwiIiwiJzlNKzlNKydcbic5TVI5TSsnXG4nOU0rTU0rJ1xuJzlNLTlNLTlNKydcbic5TStNTU0rJ1xuJzgxTSs4MU0rNTZNLTM1TS0xMk0rJ1xuJzlNK01STSsnXG4nOU0rTSsnXG4nOSdcbic5TStNTSdcbicyTSsyTTJNTSsnIl0=). Returns blank in the case of an invalid expression.

**Explanation:**

```
⁽±Ḋ                                      # group digits and non-digits together, preserving order
   ƛǍ[f;                                 # split into list of chars for non-digit items
        f                                # flattened
         (                        )      # for each item:
          nw                             #  item, wrapped in a single list
            ‛MR                          #  literal "MR"
               ‛¥⁼½d                     #  list ["¥¥","⁼⁼"] (D flag: do not decompress string)
                    Ŀ                    #  transliterate
                     ÷Ė                  #  unwrap and execute the item:
                                         #    M: push register twice
                                         #    R: always 0, also makes stack length to 1
                                         #    + & -: add and subtract respectively
                                         #      concatenates with input if stack is insufficient
                                         #    <number>: push <number> as int
                       ‟                 #  rotate the item to the back of stack
                        n±ß¥             #  if the current item is numeric, push register
                                         #    (preventing the number from being stored)
                            £            #  store to register
                             !3=ß*       #  if stack length == 3, multiply
                                   ¥     # push register
                                    D⌊=* # multiply depending on being an integer
                                         # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 146 bytes

```javascript
s=>eval(s.replace(/\d+|M[-+R]?/g,b=>`_${c?"*":""}=${b<":"?(d=c++,b):d&&b[1]?"m=``//":`m${(d=b[1])||";a"}=_;${c=!d,b>"M-"&&"m=0"}`};`,m=c=d=0)+"m")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNboMwEIX3OYUzQghqE0KiVAnUcAI22VIU82OiVBBHEEWVCDeo1E2X7T16nl6gR6CGVmlorbE0@ua98YwfolNUJeXucDT2IuVtRtuKuvwU5Vo1KfkhjxKumfcpPvuBgdehZ25JTF22UerEgxuwARqq1PGdzDwtpQnGJNbtVFXjwAo9KChjpgk2K5Raljuon8/gRNK2cWQTOk5J7IJvgKpK9RQa1jiMFDShKZ3qGArQ25wfURJVvEIUBSMkTwArH8sAYi1DckHrHq2uCPb/iYw@JDX@CHvv9MKWlo@7u7j1jfnCN6xZJ1jOB6Z1xxgbMIyGCMh0@ND1iLLpzJ/9Thk6o0yUWrdysCNIhEhk38vrqO49XamUP5FpO93pSSL2lcj5JBdbTVYoRQJ5CD5eXz7fnwHZMn17AoJkPzBcmZQy0PhHxzT@eODJkadIqUWjs84AsnXTfgE)

Creates a program based on the input and then evaluates it. Returns the empty string for invalid inputs. My favorite aspect of this solution is using `b<":"` to separate numeric strings from the other kinds of strings that can appear here.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 138 bytes

```javascript
s=>eval(s.replace(/\d+|M[-+R]?/g,b=>`_${c?"*":""}=${b<":"?(d=c++,b):d&&b[1]||`m${(d=b[1])||";a"}=_;${c=!d,b>"M-"&&"m=0"}`};`,m=c=d=0)+"m")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNbsIwEIX3nGI6QiiuHX5FBaSGE2TDNo1w4hhKFTBKItQqyQ0qddNle4@epxfoEaiTIgqtNZbG37zn8fgh2AepTNa7zN7qSB2W/JDyqdoHsZW2E7WLA6mszl1EC9ez6dyfdVYs5FOxaOZyhtc4QSx5Mw9vTTazIi4pZSGZRK1W6PX8ohCbZm5wdSBFgU5g5AvHmPlVxMIpuja2WrjhXSxF6Qi24ZJHvEsobpAcYpWBDFKVAgevAWZ5OHapCWS9kc9OaF6j8Rmh7j@RXYeh9h9h7e2e2Kjn0moPb1x7MHTtXr8SjAYXpnnFhLhgFC4Rsu5lo/Mnmkv7bv/3lb7TWOrEqkb21gy0D3r5MzyBvPZUpcSp0yx5ghwS8y1La00cKI0yk/eWIkcshIG1VOptqmPVjvXKMhXOQcMM8PPt9evjBWFi0vdnZGB6oj01SWICro46YanHnZKZiqCZ65KIyoDEaZSHbw)

Similar to [@Mukundan314's reasoning](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254718/31957), this version throws an error instead of returning a specific value.